# TornadoFX: Error while updating label inside runAsync

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I tried to implement a chat application using socket connection in Kotlin and TornadoFX library to make the GUI.
The problem comes when I try to launch the client because it keeps waiting a message from the Server although I put that code that update the label and receive the message inside a runAsync. I red the TornadoFX documentation and saw youtube videos but I cannot come to the solution.
I know that the issue is that the program is stuck in that block but can't figure how to do it.

```
    class MyFirstView: View("Chat"){

        var input: TextField by singleAssign()
        var test = SimpleStringProperty()
        val client: Client by inject()

        init {
            client.connect()
            val t = thread(true) {
                 while (true) {
                      random = client.getMessage()
                      println(random)
                      Platform.runLater { test.set(random) }
                 }
            }
        }

        override val root = vbox {
            hbox {
                label(test) {
                    bind(test)
                }
            }
            hbox {
                label("Write here some text")
                input = textfield()
            }
            hbox {
                button("Send") {
                    action{
                        client.writer.println(input.text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only update UI elements on the UI thread, so if you want to manipulate the UI from a background thread, you need to wrap that particular code in `runLater { }`.

On another note, you shouldn't manipulate the text of the textfield or store ui element references with singleAssign. Instead you should bind your textfield to a StringProperty and manipulate the value instead. This is covered in the guide, so check it out :)

Comment: I updated my code and change the constructor and it seems that work well.
I added a thread inside the init block